# Where to locate a dir without W^X? (/data/local/tmp)

Tags: android-10, termux, busybox

I have an Android 10 LGK22 No-Rooted without option to do it (so rooting is out of the question/solution). Which is not ridiculously forcing W^X (the option to stop a binary from being executed from a home directory). At least on Termux.

However I'm trying to execute a `busybox` binary from SimpleSSHD's home folder. But I keep getting errors: `permission denied`. Same happens with `Simple-Busybox`, can't execute `busybox` on its own home folder.

I know it's doable within the `tmp` folder, but the default location on my phone `/data/local/tmp` is not world readable/writable/executable `777`.

**Is there any subfolder within /data/local/tmp with `x` permissions or somewhere else to execute a binary from?**

Comment: On all devices I have encountered you can read, write and execute data from `/data/local/tmp`. On some devices you can't get the directory listing but if you know the exact file name you can use it.

Comment: W^X is enforced on Android Q+. Your Termux app must be targeting API level below Q. // `/data/local/tmp/` is RWX for `adb shell` (UID 2000 and context `u:r:shell:s0`), not for world.

Comment: @Robert That's right. Usually with other vendors I can go into /data/local/tmp and copy busybox into it and be able to execute. However when I descend into that particular folder I don't have permission to even read.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I've been using several devices with Android Q, it depends on the vendor itself. With a Lenovo tablet with the greatest and latest Android not even Termux had the option to execute binaries downloaded and written with its own UID but on `/data/local/0/tmp` it did have the option for everyone to write, execute and delete (its own files, deleting files made by a different UID it was problematic but reading was not an issue).

Comment: do I understand right you can't execute termux binaries /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin (like busybox) not even from within termux app itself?

Comment: @alecxs On the Lenovo tablet (which is NOT the device I'm working on), yes. I DID NOT have the option to executed a copy of `busybox` downloaded with Termux on `/data/data/com.termux/filex/usr/bin`. But as I said, that's NOT the device I'm asking about.

With the LG device, I can't execute a `busybox` binary from home folder of SimpleSSHD.